# RMI TCP connection error when starting Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting RMI TCP connection error when I start my Spring Boot application. I don't even see the Spring Boot ASCII art. I am using JDK 1.8.

Here are the error logs.

```
2017-11-14 16:23:51 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 80
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: (port 53739) op = 82
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: (port 53739) op = 80
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: (port 53739) op = 82
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: (port 53739) op = 84
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 82
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 80
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 82
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 80
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.loader - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: name = "[Ljava.rmi.server.ObjID;", codebase = ""
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.loader - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: name = "java.rmi.server.ObjID", codebase = ""
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.loader - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: name = "java.rmi.server.UID", codebase = ""
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.loader - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: name = "java.rmi.dgc.Lease", codebase = ""
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.loader - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: name = "java.rmi.dgc.VMID", codebase = ""
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.loader - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: name = "[B", codebase = ""
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 82
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 84
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 82
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 80
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 82
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.transport.tcp - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: (port 53742) op = 80
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.loader - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: name = "javax.management.ObjectName", codebase = ""
2017-11-14 16:23:52 [DEBUG] sun.rmi.server.call - RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.108: [192.168.0.108] exception: 
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:643)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1445)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:639)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For IntelliJ IDEA, go to "Edit Configurations..." and uncheck "Enable JMX agent".

I don't know about other IDEs.

Comment: You are an angel :)

Comment: Glad to know the solution helped you

Comment: how to disable this in intelij? I do not find.

Comment: On the top right side of your window look for a dropdown window where the name of your Main class is written, typically MainApplication or something like that. Click that dropdown and go to edit configurations. There you will find the option to check/uncheck enable JMX agent

Comment: *Note:* For IDEA 2022+ its 'Disable JVM agent'

Comment: Note: For IDEA 2023+ it's 'Disable JMX endpoints' ^^

Comment: For IDEA 2023, first go to Run/Debug Configurations -> Modify options -> Disable JMX endpoints.